# Jquery nested table creation clean approach

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written below code which creates a table inside another table from json response.

### Main Table Code

```
 var user = '<table width="98%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: left; margin: 0 auto;';
                user += 'border-collapse: collapse;" >';

                $.each(html.ListOfReportModelData, function (key, val) {

                    user += '<tr>';
                    user += '<td>';
                    user += '<table width="100%" id="internalTable" border="0" cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px" >';
                    if (flag == "false") {
                        user += '<tr class="GreenColor">';
                        user += '<td  style="width: 15%" class="accord">';
                        user += 'PR Number';
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td  style="width: 10%" class="accord">';
                        user += 'Created On';
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td  style="width: 10%" class="accord">';
                        user += 'Site Name';
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td style="width: 10%" class="accord">';
                        user += 'Order ID';
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td style="width: 55%" class="accord">';
                        user += 'File Name';
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '</tr>';
                    }
                    var count = 0;

                    $.each(val.Orders, function (key, child) {
                        //debugger;
                        user += '<tr class="PinkColor">';
                        if (count == 0) {
                            user += '<td valign="top" rowspan="' + val.Orders.length + '" style="width: 15%"><a href="javascript:GetFinanceData(' + "'" + val.SiteName + "','" + val.Req_Number + "'" + ');">';
                            user += val.Req_Number;
                            user += '</a></td>';
                            count = 1;
                        }
                        user += '<td valign="top" style="width: 10%">';
                        user += val.CreatedDateText;
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td valign="top" style="width: 10%">';
                        user += val.SiteName;
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td valign="top" style="width: 10%">';
                        user += child.OrderId;
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '<td style="width: 55%;break-word: word-wrap;">';
                        if (child.ShowLink) {

                            user += '<a href="javascript:Export(' + "'" + child.ID + "','" + val.SiteName + "'" + ');">';
                        }

                        user += child.Attachments_FileName;
                        if (child.ShowLink) {
                            user += '</a>';
                        }
                        user += '</td>';
                        user += '</tr>';
                    });
                    user += '<tr class="PinkColor">';
                    user += '<td colspan="5"><div id="' + val.Req_Number + '" ></div>';
                    user += '</td>';
                    user += '</tr>';

                    user += '</table>';
                    user += '</td>';
                    user += '</tr>';

                    flag = "true";

                });
                user += '</table>';
```

### Child Table Creation

```
 $.getJSON("/Home/FinancialInformation", data, function (html) {

            totalRecords = html.FinanceData.length;
            if (totalRecords == 0) {
                $('#' + Req_Number + '').empty();
                alert('No Finance Data Available!!!!!');
            }
            else {
                var Fin = '<table id=' + Req_Number + ' width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" >';
                Fin += '<tr class="GreenColor">';
                Fin += '<td class="accord" style="width: 45%">Approval Type</td>';
                Fin += '<td class="accord" style="width: 10%">Approval Required</td>';
                Fin += '<td class="accord" style="width: 15%">Approved By</td>';
                Fin += '<td class="accord" style="width: 10%">Approved By 521</td>';
                Fin += '<td class="accord" style="width: 20%">Approved Date</td>';
                Fin += '</tr>';
                $.each(html.FinanceData, function (key, val) {

                    Fin += '<tr class="PinkColor">';
                    Fin += '<td style="width: 45%">' + val.Approval_Type + '</td>';
                    Fin += '<td style="width: 10%">' + val.Approval_Required + '</td>';
                    Fin += '<td style="width: 15%">' + val.Approved_By + '</td>';
                    Fin += '<td style="width: 10%">' + val.Approved_By_521 + '</td>';
                    Fin += '<td style="width: 20%">' + val.Approved_Date + '</td>';
                    Fin += '</tr>';
                });
                Fin += '</table>';
                $('#' + Req_Number + '').empty()
                $('#' + Req_Number + '').append(Fin);
            }
        });
```

I can see my table created correctly but I see lot of cumbersome activity in creating these codes.Is there better approach to achieve the same thing?Mostly using some plugins.

Comment: Can use a template engine script

Comment: Thanks for comment.I am pure JS guy.Can you please share any link or atleast show some example.

Comment: handlebars.js or mustache.js for example. Also lots of table plugins around. Overall nothing really wrong with what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How others have said you should use a template engine like : handlebarsJS, mustacheJS, underscoreJS or maybe something like reactJS

Or if you want to keep it with jQuery, you can structure your code like :

- Instead of injecting html directly like that, you can use jQuery syntax to create each element
- You can split logic with functions
- You can use only CSS classes(no style) and add it with jQuery

Here it's an example :

```
var getParentTable = function() {
    // add style to CLASS in CSS
    return $('<table></table>').addClass('parentTableClass');
};

var getInternalTable = function() {
    return $('<table></table>')
        .addClass('childTableClass')
        .attr('id', 'internalTable');
};

var getRow = function(classValue) {
    return $('<tr></tr>').addClass(classValue);
};

var getCol = function(textValue, classValue) {
    return $('<td></td>')
                .addClass(classValue)
                .text(textValue);
};

var parentTable = getParentTable();
parentTable.append(internalTable);

 $.each(html.ListOfReportModelData, function (key, val) {
    var internalTable = getInternalTable();
    var simpleRow = getRow();
    var simpleCol = getCol();
    var row1 = getRow('GreenColor');
    var row3 = getRow('PinkColor');

    row1
        .append(getCol('PR Number', 'td1 accord'))
        .append(getCol('Created On', 'td2 accord'))
        .append(getCol('Site Name', 'td3 accord'))
        .append(getCol('Order ID', 'td4 accord'))
        .append(getCol('File Name', 'td5 accord'));

    internalTable.append(row1);

    $.each(val.Orders, function (key, child) {  
        var row2 = getRow('PinkColor');
            .append(getCol(val.Req_Number, 'td1 accord'))
            .append(getCol(val.CreatedDateText, 'td2 accord'))
            .append(getCol(val.SiteName, 'td3 accord'))
            .append(getCol(child.OrderId, 'td4 accord'))
            .append(getCol(child.ShowLink, 'td5 accord'));

        internalTable.append(row2);
     });

    internalTable.append(row3);

    simpleCol.append(internalTable);
    simpleRow.append(simpleCol);

    parentTable.append(simpleRow);
 });
```